# move imported folders from parent one level higher

Tags: svn

I imported my trunk from svn, but did a mistake  I imported it under 1 project, the problem is that my trunk contains some modules, each of them should be a diferent project. Is there a way to move them  without the need to reimport from svn (it takes much, that's why I'm avoiding it.) I use eclipse.

```
WorkspaceA/Name/{modules} - where modules is each of my as project desired folders.

to 

WorkspaceA/{modules} - where modules are individual projects still with versioning
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the rest of your team agrees with your desired new directory structure, you simply need to `svn move` each module one level up, then `svn rm` the Name directory. Then you `svn commit` your moves to get them on the server. I'm not certain how to accomplish this using Eclipse tools but it ought to be possible. If you need to, you can always install the command-line or TortoiseSVN tools to get it working from outside Eclipse then just re-import your project from  existing directories on your machine (rather than a full checkout from SVN which I assume is the time-consuming part of your question).